# Modulo 2 Division

Tags: matlab

I am trying to implement modulo 2 division in MATLAB but every time I ran this code, I got an error. Could somebody help me to correct this? I am trying to convert [this Python code](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/modulo-2-binary-division/) to MATLAB :

```
function [reminder] = mod2div(divident, divisor)
% Number of bits to be XORed at a time
pick = size(divisor, 2);
tmp = divident(1 : pick);
while pick < size(divident,2)
   if int2str(tmp(1)) == '1'
      tmp = bitxor(divisor, tmp);
      tmp = [tmp,divident(pick)];

   else
      mi=uint8(zeros(1,pick));
      tmp = bitxor(mi, tmp) ;
      tmp = [tmp,divident(pick)];
   end    
   pick = pick + 1;
end   
if int2str(tmp(1)) == '1'    
   tmp = bitxor(divisor, tmp);
else
   mi=zeros(1,pick);
   tmp = bitxor(mi, tmp) ; 
end
reminder = tmp ;
end
```

Comment: which error did you get?

Comment: Matrix dimensions must agree.
Error in mod2div (line 7)
        tmp = bitxor(divisor, tmp);

Comment: but they are same size

Comment: Can you add a [mcve]

Comment: i am new to matlab

Comment: That is irrelevant, please, add code that we can tests, including inputs.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "modulo 2 division" ? Do you mean "integer division using base 2 representation " ? For example : 111 divided by 101 gives quotient  1 and remainder 10 ?